# Dynamic ContextMenu In CodeBehind

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I just want to add ContextMenu for several objects that I create dynamically, but 
The only way I found is to create ContextMenu in runtime like this:

```
ContextMenu pMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem item1  = new MenuItem();
MenuItem item2  = new MenuItem();

//I have about 10 items
//...
item1.Header = "item1";
item1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(item1_Click);
pMenu.Items.Add(item1);

item2.Header = "item2";
item2.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(item2_Click);
pMenu.Items.Add(item2);

//and so on
```

It works, however, in WinForms I was able to drop ContextMenuStrip component to my form and define items and events very quickly w/o writing any code. Is it possible in WPF?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can define your `ContextMenu` in resources and bind it to any control you needed. Check this out:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Send" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="a_button"
            ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}" >
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ok, but I create objects dynamically, so how to bind it in runtime?

Comment: @Michael: You should be able to get the ContextMenu at runtime via `var pMenu = (ContextMenu)this.Resources["MyContextMenu"];` Then you can assign this variable to your dynamically created control.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only thing I cannot understand is why in WPF I have to do all this magic and there is no appropriate component and GUI in IDE to make things much easier as they must be.

Comment: @Michael In WPF, your forms are not your application. Your data is. This is quite different from WinForms where your forms are your application and the data gets added to form objects. In WPF, your data is your application and your form objects are just a pretty layer to allow users to interact with your data layer. Once you get used to that, WPF becomes much easier :)

Answer (score 12):

Additionaly you can put commands on the menuItem...

Like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="MyContextMenuItem
                  Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"
                  CommandTarget="{Binding 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
```

CommandTarget can be very important, if you use your contextMenu on different controls. I often use the FindAncestor here, to identify the caller.

Comment: I use PlacementTarget to get the caller

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me, InsertQuery/DeleteQuery are two ICommand methods defined in ViewModel.

```
  <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Insert"
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.InsertQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                      Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteQuery, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
  </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```