# WPF ContextMenu bound to 3 Listboxes on right-click

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox, contextmenu

I have three tabs and each has a listbox with different types of files.

When I right-click on an item in the listbox, I want a ContextMenu with "New, Edit and Delete" as Item headers.

I guess I could have a ContextMenu for each listbox, and then have a seperate method for each header, such as:

```
               <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="NewEditDeleteAdvCalcFileContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Name="NewAdv" Header="New" Click="NewAdv_Click" />
                        <MenuItem Name="EditAdv" Header="Edit" Click="EditAdv_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Name="DeleteAdv" Header="Delete" Click="DeleteAdv_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

But really, I hope there is a better way.

I saw this post which shows the [ContextMenu as Static Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582611/2090211)

and this seems to be something I would like to do.
In the same thread it is suggested to use commands:
[ContextMenu with Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584218/2090211)

and with that I'm hoping I can get the type of the ListBoxItem that was clicked, because I need that. A new file type B must be handled differently than a new file type C, but I don't want a gazillion contextmenus and New/Edit/Delete methods.

So, currently I have this higher up in my xaml file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="NewEditDeleteContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="New" 
                  Command="{Binding Path=NewFileCommand}"  
                  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" 
                  Command="{Binding Path=EditFileCommand}"  
                  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                  Command="{Binding Path=DeleteFileCommand}"  
                  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then a listbox in the tabItem:

```
<ListBox Name="CalcFilesListBox" 
                     Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding CalcFilesList}" 
                     PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" 
                     ContextMenu="{StaticResource NewEditDeleteContextMenu}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="CalcFileListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
```

**Question #1**

How do I get the rightclick of a ListBoxItem to show the ContextMenu, which is now a static resource?
Because in my xaml.cs I had this:

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // SelectItemOnRightClick(e);
        NewEditDeleteContextMenu.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
        NewEditDeleteContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

But now I have an error saying:

> The name 'NewEditDeleteContextMenu' does not exist in the current context.

because originally I had the contextmenu as part of the ListBox such as:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
...
```

But as far as I could see that would mean a separate ContextMenu for each ListBox.

**Question #2**

Is the correct way to use a command, let's say NewFileCommand for the New item header in the ContextMenu (shown in the UserControl.Resources block of code) to do the following:

In my ViewModel:

```
 public RelayCommand<string> NewFileCommand { get; private set; }
```

and then in the ViewModel's constructor:

```
 public CalcViewModel()
    {
        NewFileCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(NewFile);
    }

 public void NewFile(object sender)
    {
         //Determine the type of file, based on the ListBoxItem's DataContext. 
That is, supposing the ListBoxItem is the object being passed as the sender.
    }
```

Basically, I want one ContextMenu bound to the different ListBox components, and this should pop up on a rightclick, and when for instance the New item is chosen on the ContextMenu, I want to determine the type of the file that has been bound to the ListBox.
E.g.: ListBox 1 is bound to a collection of file type B. ListBox 2 is bound to a collection of file type C. When I rightclick on an item in ListBox 2, and choose New, I need to make a new file of type C.

**Question #3**

This isn't a very intricate View. I haven't used a MVVM framework because so far I haven't thought that the time it would take me to learn one would be worth it, but considering this scenario, and a simpler case for a double-click on the ListBoxItems that can be seen in one of the blocks of code, would you recommend the use of a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going in the right direction, you code just needs a bit of updating. First, don't need any right-click handlers -- if a control has a `ContextMenu` set, right-clicking will invoke that `ContextMenu`. Having a `ContextMenu` as a `StaticResource` and attaching it to multiple controls creates a bit of a problem because of a bug in .NET where a ContextMenu doesn't update its `DataContext` after initially setting it. That means if you first invoke the menu on listbox #2, you'll get the selected item in that listbox... but if you then invoke it on listbox #3, you'll still get the selected item in listbox #2. But there's a way around this.

First, let's look at the context menu and how it's bound to a list box:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="New" Command="{Binding DataContext.NewFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
</ContextMenu>

...

<ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Files1}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}"/>
```

`PlacementTarget` is the control the `ContextMenu` is attached to. Explicitly binding the menu's data context to `PlacementTarget` ensures it's pointing to the correct `ListBox` every time it's invoked. Commands like "Edit" and "Delete" that deal with list items are then easy: Just bind the `CommandParameter` (not the `CommandTarget` as you did) to the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem`. The item you want to edit or delete will then be given as a parameter to the command.

Since you used `RelayCommand` I'm assuming you used GalaSoft's MVVM framework. In that case here's how your "Delete" command might look:

```
public RelayCommand<object> DeleteFileCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand<object>( DeleteFile_Executed, DeleteFile_CanExecute );

private static bool DeleteFile_CanExecute( object file )
{
    return file != null;
}

private static void DeleteFile_Executed( object file )
{
    var filetype = file.GetType();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( string.Format( "Deleting file {0} of type {1}", file, file.GetType() ) );

    // if( filetype == typeof( FileTypeA ) ) DeleteFileTypeA( file as FileTypeA );
    // else if( filetype == typeof( FileTypeB ) ) DeleteFileTypeB( file as FileTypeB );
    // etc...
}
```

The "New" command will be a bit tricker because you want to be able to create a new item whether an item is selected or not. So we'll bind the `CommandParameter` to the `ListBox` itself. Unfortunately there's not a good way to get the type of item the `ListBox` contains. It could contain multiple types of items, or no items at all. You could give it an `x:Name` then look at the name in your command handler, but what I choose to do is put the type of item this `ListBox` handles as the `Tag` parameter of the `ListBox`. `Tag` is a bit of extra data you can use for whatever purpose you like:

```
<ListBox Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Files1}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}" Tag="{x:Type local:FileTypeA}"/>
```

Now we can define our "New" command handlers like this:

```
private static bool NewFile_CanExecute( ListBox listbox ) { return true; }

private static void NewFile_Executed( ListBox listbox )
{
    var filetype = listbox.Tag as Type;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( string.Format( "Creating new file of type {0}", filetype ) );

    // if( filetype == typeof( FileTypeA ) ) CreateNewFileTypeA();
    // else if( filetype == typeof( FileTypeB ) ) CreateNewFileTypeB();
    // etc...
}
```

As for whether this scenario warrants an MVVM or not, you can certainly put your three file lists in a ViewModel, along with code that actually creates, edits, and deletes the files, and have your commands in the Window invoke the code in the ViewModel. I usually don't, though, until the scenario becomes more complicated.

Comment: I've wanted to thank you earlier this week but I'm still changing a few things and refactoring code. I'll mark this as the answer once I've tested everything. I also have a treeview in one of the tabs, but I thought I would first get the listboxes right as they're probably easier. I don't use GalaSoft's MVVM framework, but I'm trying to work your answer into what I have. So, I might ask for further clarification, but thank you so much, you have been an enormous help!

Comment: Okay, so is it possible to share the contextmenu with a treeview as well? I actually have 2 listboxes and a treeview. I foresee trouble with the New command, where I use the Tag on the Listbox to send the file type through. If I send an object (instead of Listbox) to the command then I lose the Tag property, not so? Otherwise I could just add a separate contextmenu for the treeview I guess.

Comment: I assume you can.  Have you tried it?  Assuming your treeview only contains one type of item, you can still use the Tag method -- just use the superclass FrameworkElement instead of ListBox in your CanExecute and Execute methods.