# Types on WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a Treeview on one of three tabs. The other two tabs contain Listboxes.
The Treeview has parents and children, only two layers. (Not sure of the correct terminology here).

When the user clicks on an item in the Treeview, there is a Contextmenu with New/Edit/Delete options.
Due to the other two tabs using the same Contextmenu it has been implemented in a specific way. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465228/wpf-contextmenu-bound-to-3-listboxes-on-right-click) is the background to it.
The parents have type TemplateFamily, and the children are of type TemplateParameter.
I use the Tag to send through extra information so that I know from which tab the request comes.

Here is the wpf for the TabItem:

```
<TabItem Header="Template Files" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateFamilyList}" 
                      Margin="20"
                      ContextMenu="{StaticResource NewEditDeleteContextMenu}"
                      Tag="{x:Type domain:TemplateParameter}">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helper:TemplateFamily}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateParameterMembers}" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Template.Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TemplateParameterMembers.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                            <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TemplateParameterListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                            </Style>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type domain:TemplateParameter}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" (" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParameterID}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" ; " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sequence}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=")" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
        </TabItem>
```

Here is the ContextMenu:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="NewEditDeleteContextMenu"
                 DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="New" 
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.NewFileCommand}"  
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" 
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.EditFileCommand}"  
                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteFileCommand}"  
                  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
```

So when the user right-clicks on a child node (TemplateParameter) then all is fine, but when the user clicks on a parent node (TemplateFamily) then the cast as a TemplateParameter below does not work, `selectedTemplateParameter` is null and the cast in the else statement doesn't work either.

In the ViewModel I have this:

```
public void NewFile(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {

        System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView = frameworkElement as System.Windows.Controls.TreeView;              
        TemplateParameter selectedTemplateParameter = treeView.SelectedItem as TemplateParameter;

        if (selectedTemplateParameter != null)
        {
        ...
        }
        else
        {
            TemplateFamily templatefam = treeView.SelectedItem as TemplateFamily;
        }

    }
```

**So my question is**, how can I get the parent's type when clicked and the New option is chosen (the Edit and Delete is of little consequence at present)?
Actually, even if the user clicks on a child, I just need the parent cast as a TemplateFamily to do the functionality.

Comment: ViewModel should know absolutely nothing about UI concerns. The fact that NewFile has `FrameworkElement` as an arg is a giant red flag.

Comment: What is TemplateFamilyList and how are your types defined?

Comment: BTW, I cannot reproduce your issue. I get a non-null result from the second cast (in the 'else'-branch). So I suppose there's something other in your code that we don't see here. Nevertheless, your approach violates MVVM, as @LynnCrumbling correctly mentions.

Comment: Here is the link to my previous question which explains how it happened that I used FrameworkElement. Perhaps suggestions as to how I could correctly implement MVVM would be more appropriate there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465228/wpf-contextmenu-bound-to-3-listboxes-on-right-click

Comment: @mm8, ObservableCollection<TemplateFamily> TemplateFamilyList. I'm not sure what you want when you ask how my types are defined.

Comment: I see that I often right-clicked on a parent without first selecting it. That explains why it would return a null even for the cast to the TemplateFamily.

Comment: Post the definition of your classes.

Comment: I came right. With realising that I often right-clicked on the parent without selecting it, I could give the user a meaningful message in that scenario. If the parent is selected and then right-clicked, the cast to a TemplateFamily works. Thanks for everyone's input.